# Unable to see Invocation logs for App Service functions

Tags: azure-functions

When I publish function code (Runtime version: 3.0.14287.0 (~3) to an App Service, everything appears to be running but I cannot see any invocation logs in the Monitor page of any functions in the portal - it's always blank.  I have timer-triggered functions, which should show up.

I am using an ARM script to deploy a resource group that contains an App Service.  The deployment consists of the following resources:

```
Microsoft.Insights/components
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults
Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts
Microsoft.Web/serverfarms
Microsoft.Web/sites
```

I can see the function traces in Application Insights using something like this query:

```
traces 
| order by timestamp desc
| where message contains 'telemetry'
```

I don't know if it is related, but in the App Service Overview page, I do see the following warning:

```
Storage is not configured properly, Function scaling will be limited. Click to learn more.
```

I'm using the following App Service appsettings to connect it to App Insights:

```
APPINSIGHT_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY: <instrumentation key from app insights>
AzureWebJobsDashboard: <storage acct connect string>
AzureWebJobsStorage: <storage acct  connect string>
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION ~3
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME dotnet
```

The storage account has the following objects, that were created automatically.

```
BLOB <name>-leases
BLOB azure-webjobs-hosts
BLOB azure-webjobs-secrets
QUEUES <name>-control-[00,01,02,03]
QUEUES <name>-workitems
TABLE <name>History
TABLE <name>Instances
TABLE AzureWebJobsHostLogs202008
TABLE AzureWebJobsHostLogscommon
```

Here's my hosts.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Debug",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the file `host.json`, for the filed "Function", set its value to Trace. Then it can be logged into application insights.

Sample `host.json` for Azure function v2, which can log trace messages to Application Insights:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

In Azure portal, navigate to your function app -> in the function app settings, then change log level to trace in the host.json.

[image]

For more details, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#log-configuration-in-hostjson) on how to set log level for function v1 or v2.

**Note:** the invocation log in app insight and Monitor has **delay time**. After doing operation, wait for 5 minutes and check again. You can go the app insight check first. If app insight does not have log, Monitor will not have.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I tried your suggestion and no change - no Invocation Traces in Functions->Monitor page.  As I mentioned, I can see almost up-to-date trace messages in App Insights.  I'm deploying to an App Service, is that difference than a Function App?

Comment: The issue is very odd. Could you please recreate a new function and recreate a new app insight.

Comment: I delete/recreate regularly via ARM scripts.  Should this be posted as an issue to github?

Comment: Could you give me detailed ARM scripts so that I can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes, I can.  How do I get them to you?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this configuration:

```
"Host.Results": "Error"
```

in your host.json logLevel settings is the problem.

This setting controls the logging of requests.

"These runtime-generated logs indicate success or failure of a function. All of these logs are written at Information level. If you filter at Warning or above, you won't see any of this data."

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2

Try setting this to 'Trace' and I expect you'll see invocation logs for all requests (and not just errors).

Answer (score 0):

I found that explicitly disabling the application insights sampling settings in the **host.json** fixed this issue

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Debug",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace",
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem was started after cleanup  azure service. The insight service required to have a second type of resource of type **Log Analytics workplace**. In my case after re-create an analytics service and connect to function(replace new connection string & key) Invocation Traces shows as normal.

[Insights required type img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxtHk.png)

Answer (score 0):

If everything seems to be configured properly, the cause may lie somewhere else. In my case some of  the Application Insights **domains were blocked by my ad-blocker**. This resulted in failed requests to the Application Insights APIs, making it appear as if the invocations were not loading on the monitor page.

The invocation logs were visible in the Azure Portal again after whitelisting these domains:

```
*.applicationinsights.io
*.loganalytics.io
```